# Gradle mavenLocal finds jar but doesn't include for compile

Tags: java, gradle, gradlew

in `build.gradle` I have:

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.test:test:1.2.1'
}
```

`gradlew build` finds the jar but I can't use any of the classes in the jar as I just get:

```
error: cannot find symbol
symbol: class MatrixMessageHandler
```

is there another step that's required to get the jar to be used in the project?

edit:
I suspect it's a gradle thing. The jar has a dependency on `activemq-broker-5.8.0` but gradle is ignoring it and using `5.15.8` which doesn't exist in the local maven repo. I suspect this is what's causing the problem:

```
11:12:41.670 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.internal.VersionConfiguringAction] Using version '5.15.8' for dependency 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.8.0'
```

for some reason gradle is making up a random version to replace the one in the local maven repo (`5.8.0`)

Comment: `compile` is deprecated

Comment: implementation doesn't work either

Comment: I was just suggesting that `compile` is `deprecated ` didn't mean it to fix the question :P

Comment: Could you show more of the error ?

Comment: it's just a standard symbol not found error public class MessageHandler implements MatrixMessageHandler {
                                       ^
  symbol: class MatrixMessageHandler - MatrixMessageHandler is in the jar brought in via mavenLocal

Comment: Has anyone found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason gradle was replacing the valid version of a dependency with a previous version:

```
11:12:41.670 [DEBUG] [io.spring.gradle.dependencymanagement.internal.VersionConfiguringAction] Using version '5.15.8' for dependency 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.8.0'
```

`5.15.8` used to be in the `pom` in the local maven repo but I deleted that version of the jar and deleted the gradle caches but I couldn't get gradle to forget it.

```
rm -r ~/.gradle/caches/*
```

this previous dependency does not exist in the local maven repo:

```
org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.15.8
```

the up to date dependency exists in the local maven repo:

```
org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.8.0
```

The solution was to force gradle to use the up to date dependency:

```
compile 'org.apache.activemq:activemq-broker:5.8.0'
```

which isn't an option if you don't know what the dependencies are. In this case I do as I developed the project. Clearing the global cache did nothing so I deleted the `build` directory, removed the above line from `build.gradle` and now it's working.

So the real issue appears to be that gradle was not resolving dependencies in `mavenLocal()` due to a stale cache/build.